# Readonly Textbox, content change event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I have html page and need to fire an event when changing the content. The text box is in read-only status and it's value change by some other jquery functions. I search through the internet and most of forums said that below code will work.

```
$('#some_text_box').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
    console.log('fired');
});
```

But this not works for me.

Comment: `$('#some_text_box').on('input propertychange paste change', function() {
    console.log('fired');
}).change();`

Comment: The answers on the question marked as duplicated wasn't really that helpfull in your case so I gave a new answer there that should contain what you're looking for